# Unable to send mail from jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, hudson

I am writing script which send mail using jenkins-cli.jar line is.

java -jar /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s serverip/ jenkins -s Mailing -p FROM="@mail.com" -p BCCList="***@mail.com" -p SUBJECT="mail" -p MESSAGE="Dear Recipient,\nPlease find the info below \n\n\nThanks & Regards,\nMy Team"

but getting below error:

The java class could not be loaded. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (hudson/cli/CLI) bad major version at offset=6

please assist me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you're running JDK version 1.6 or later. 
Check the JAVA_HOME declaration by running `java -version` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Johnny cen.I will check with latest JAVA once.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Myservername/
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.url(CLIConnectionFactory.java:30)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:463)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)

Comment: Seems you forgot to add the protocol or sth. Try adding "http://" in front of serverip

Comment: I added the "http://" but getting........                                                     Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://myservername        at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:274)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:134)
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:469)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)
        Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Check the server ip and port?

Comment: Hi Jonny,

I added server and port name but getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.cli.CLI.flushURLConnection(CLI.java:310)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:285)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:134)
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:469)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)"